# How to find the 3-direction Lorentz boost transformation on Dirac spinor?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, lie-algebra, spinors

I am struggling to work out correct Lorentz transformation for a boost in the 3-direction on a Dirac spinor, $u(p)$. According to Peskin & Schroeder pg. 46, I need to use the equations:

$$S^{0i} = -\frac{i}{2}\pmatrix{\sigma ^i &0 \\ 0 & -\sigma ^i} \hspace{10mm} (3.26)$$
$$\Lambda _{\frac{1}{2}} = exp\left(-\frac{i}{2}\omega _{\mu \nu} S^{\mu \nu} \right) \hspace{6mm} (3.30) $$

Where (3.26) gives me the generator for the boost and (3.30) gives the transformation.

**My Attempt**

Using the above,
$$S^{03} = -\frac{i}{2}\pmatrix{\sigma ^3 & 0 \\ 0 &-\sigma ^3}$$
$$ \Lambda _{\frac{1}{2}} = exp \left (-\frac{1}{4}\omega_{03}\pmatrix{\sigma ^3 & 0 \\ 0 &-\sigma ^3} \right)  $$

Then the transformation would be: 
$$ u(p) =  exp \left [-\frac{1}{4}\omega_{03}\pmatrix{\sigma ^3 & 0 \\ 0 &-\sigma ^3} \right] u(p) $$

**The Issue**

The book states, on the first line of (3.49), that the transformation is instead:

$$ u(p) = exp \left[-\frac{1}{2}\eta \pmatrix{\sigma ^3 & 0 \\ 0 &-\sigma ^3} \right] u(p)$$

Where $\eta$ is the rapidity (whatever that is). I can't see where the $\omega_{\mu \nu}$ has gone, do they group it in with the $\eta$? Thanks!

Comment: Leaving spinors aside, have you compared (3.21) to (3.48) for the hyperbolic rotations of the simplest boost? What is the infinitesimal angle of this rotation? [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidity).

Comment: @G.Smith Ah, sorry, I meant $\omega_{03}$ to match the $S^{03}$ generator - will edit

Comment: @CosmasZachos I had not, I think this would make the boost, setting $\omega_{03} = -\omega_{30}= \beta$:  $\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 & \beta \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \beta & 0 & 0 & 1} $.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Taking my result for the transformation, 
$$ u(p) = exp \left[-\frac{1}{4}\omega_{03} \pmatrix{\sigma^3 & 0 \\ 0 & -\sigma ^3} \right]u(p)$$, 

And setting $\eta = \frac{\omega_{03}}{2}$, I recover the stated result: 

$$u(p) = exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\eta \pmatrix{\sigma^3 & 0 \\ 0 & -\sigma ^3}\right]u(p) $$

I think $\omega$ is a real number. This is the only way I can see it working out - why they don't absorb the other $-\frac{1}{2}$ into $\eta$ escapes me, though.

Comment: The correct way, which hasn't been mentioned yet, is to notice that the sum in the exponential yields $\omega_{\mu\nu}S^{\mu\nu}=\omega_{03}S^{03}+\omega_{30}S^{30}=2\omega_{03}S^{03}$ due to the antisymmetric nature of both $S^{\mu\nu}$ and $\omega_{\mu\nu}$. Setting $\omega_{03}=\eta$ yields the correct result.

Comment: @pjHart1000 Thank you so much. I wish you'd been here 10 months ago! But satisfying to see the answer. If you write this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @shadowbiscuit I have added it as an answer, per your request. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us evaluate the sum in the exponential:
\begin{equation}
-\frac{i}{2}\omega_{\mu\nu}S^{\mu\nu}=-\frac{i}{2}(\omega_{03}S^{03}+\omega_{30}S^{30}).
\end{equation}
Due to $S^{\mu\nu}$ and $\omega_{\mu\nu}$ being antisymmetric, we get:
\begin{equation}
-\frac{i}{2}(\omega_{03}S^{03}+\omega_{30}S^{30})=-\frac{i}{2}(\omega_{03}S^{03}+(-\omega_{03})(-S^{03})) = -i\,\omega_{03}S^{03}.
\end{equation}
Now set $\omega_{03}=\eta$ (on page 40 in Peskin & Schroeder, they do the same for a boost in the $x$-direction, with $\omega_{01}=\eta$ instead). Thus:
\begin{equation}
\exp\left(-\frac{i}{2}\omega_{\mu\nu}S^{\mu\nu}\right) = \exp\left(-i\eta\left(-\frac{i}{2}\begin{pmatrix}\sigma^i&0\\0&-\sigma^i\end{pmatrix}\right)\right)=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\eta\begin{pmatrix}\sigma^i&0\\0&-\sigma^i\end{pmatrix}\right).
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

Let us first find the boost of the momentum four-vector ($p^\mu$). In the particle rest frame, $p^\mu$ is given by, $p^\mu = (m, \textbf{0)}$. Now we go to a boosted frame in the 3-direction. In the boosted frame, we define, $p^\mu = (E, \textbf{p})$. Then we have,
%
\begin{align}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        E\\
        p^3
\end{pmatrix}
= \mathrm{exp}\left[\eta
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\right]
\begin{pmatrix}
    m\\
    0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Let us define, $A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$.
%
Then we have,
%
\begin{align}
    A^2 &= 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
= I_{2}\\
%
\implies A^3 &= A^2 \cdot A = I_{2} A = A\\
%
\implies A^{2n} &= I_{2}\\
%
\implies A^{2n +1} &= A
\end{align}
%
\begin{align}
    \mathrm{exp}\left[\eta
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\right]
&= e^{\eta A} = I_{2} + \eta A + \frac{\eta^2 A^2}{2!} + \frac{\eta^3 A^3}{3!} + \frac{\eta^4 A^4}{4!} + \frac{\eta^5 A^5}{5!} + \cdots\nonumber\\
%
&= I_{2} + \eta A + \frac{\eta^2}{2!} I_{2} + \frac{\eta^3 A}{3!} + \frac{\eta^4}{4!} I_{2} + \frac{\eta^5 A}{5!} + \cdots\nonumber\\
%
&= I_{2} \left(\frac{\eta^2}{2!}  + \frac{\eta^4}{4!} + \cdots \right) + A \left(\eta + \frac{\eta^3}{3!} + \frac{\eta^5}{5!} + \cdots \right)\nonumber\\
%
&= I_{2} \cosh{\eta} + A \sinh{\eta}\nonumber\\
%
&= \cos{\eta}
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
+ \sin{\eta}
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Then we have,
\begin{align}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        E\\
        p^3
    \end{pmatrix}
    &= \left[\cos{\eta}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0\\
        0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
    + \sinh{\eta}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1\\
        1 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \right]
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m\\
        0
    \end{pmatrix}
    = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
        m \cosh{\eta}\\
        m\sinh{\eta}
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
where, $\eta$ is the rapidity. So we have, $E = m \cosh{\eta}$ and $p^3 = m \sinh{\eta}$. Now we look at boost of the column vector, $u(p) = \sqrt{m} \begin{pmatrix}
    \xi\\
    \xi
\end{pmatrix}$. While considering the boost along 3-direction, we have the boosting matrix given by,
\begin{align}
    \Lambda_{\frac{1}{2}} &= \mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac{i}{2} \omega_{\mu\nu} S^{\mu\nu}\right) = \mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac{i}{2} \omega_{03} S^{03}\right)\nonumber\\
    %
    &= \mathrm{exp}\left[-\frac{1}{4} \omega_{03}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \sigma^3 & 0\\
        0 & - \sigma^3
    \end{pmatrix}\right]
    = \mathrm{exp}\left[-\frac{\eta}{2}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \sigma^3 & 0\\
        0 & - \sigma^3
    \end{pmatrix}\right]
\end{align}
%
where, we defined, $\eta = \omega_{03}/2$. So, the boosted version of $u(p)$ is,
%
\begin{align}
    u(p) &= \Lambda_{\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt{m}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \xi\\
        \xi
    \end{pmatrix}
    = \mathrm{exp}\left[-\frac{\eta}{2}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \sigma^3 & 0\\
        0 & - \sigma^3
    \end{pmatrix}\right] \sqrt{m}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \xi\\
        \xi
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Now, we note that, $\sigma^3 =
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & - 1
\end{pmatrix}
\implies (\sigma^3)^2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & - 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & - 1
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
    0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} =I_{2}
\implies (\sigma^3)^{2n} = I_{2}$ and $(\sigma^{3})^{2n + 1} = \sigma^{3}$. Proceeding as before, by defining $B = \begin{pmatrix} \sigma^3 & 0\\ 0 & - \sigma^3 \end{pmatrix}$, we can prove,
\begin{align}
    \mathrm{exp}\left[-\frac{\eta}{2}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \sigma^3 & 0\\
        0 & - \sigma^3
    \end{pmatrix}\right] = \cosh{(\eta/2)}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        I_{2} & 0 \\
        0 & I_{2}
    \end{pmatrix} - \sinh{(\eta/2)}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \sigma^3 & 0 \\
        0 & - \sigma^3
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
%
Hence we find,
%
\begin{align}
    u(p) &= \mathrm{exp}\left[-\frac{\eta}{2}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \sigma^3 & 0\\
        0 & - \sigma^3
    \end{pmatrix}\right] \sqrt{m}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \xi\\
        \xi
    \end{pmatrix}\nonumber\\
    &= \left[\cosh{(\eta/2)}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        I_{2} & 0 \\
        0 & I_{2}
    \end{pmatrix} - \sinh{(\eta/2)}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \sigma^3 & 0 \\
        0 & - \sigma^3
    \end{pmatrix}\right] \sqrt{m}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \xi\\
        \xi
    \end{pmatrix}\nonumber\\
    &= \left[
    \begin{matrix}
         I_{2}\cosh{(\eta/2)} - \sigma^3 \sinh{(\eta/2)} & 0\\
        0 & I_{2} \cosh{(\eta/2)} + \sigma^3 \sinh{(\eta/2)}\\
    \end{matrix}\right] \sqrt{m}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \xi\\
        \xi
    \end{pmatrix}\nonumber\\
    &= \left[
    \begin{matrix}
        \left(\frac{e^{\eta/2} + e^{-\eta/2}}{2}\right) I_{2} - \left(\frac{e^{\eta/2} - e^{-\eta/2}}{2}\right) \sigma^3 & 0\\
        0 & \left(\frac{e^{\eta/2} + e^{-\eta/2}}{2}\right) I_{2} + \left(\frac{e^{\eta/2} - e^{-\eta/2}}{2}\right) \sigma^3\\
    \end{matrix}\right] \sqrt{m}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \xi\\
        \xi
    \end{pmatrix}\nonumber\\
    &= \left[
    \begin{matrix}
        e^{\eta/2} \left( \frac{I_{2} - \sigma^3}{2}\right) + e^{-\eta/2} \left( \frac{I_{2} + \sigma^3}{2}\right) & 0\\
        0 & e^{\eta/2} \left( \frac{I_{2} + \sigma^3}{2}\right) + e^{-\eta/2} \left( \frac{I_{2} - \sigma^3}{2}\right)\\
    \end{matrix}\right] \sqrt{m}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \xi\\
        \xi
    \end{pmatrix}\nonumber\\
    &= \left[
    \begin{matrix}
        \left(\sqrt{m} e^{\eta/2}\right) \left( \frac{I_{2} - \sigma^3}{2}\right) + \left(\sqrt{m} e^{-\eta/2}\right) \left( \frac{I_{2} + \sigma^3}{2}\right)\\
        \left(\sqrt{m} e^{\eta/2}\right) \left( \frac{I_{2} + \sigma^3}{2}\right) + \left(\sqrt{m} e^{-\eta/2}\right) \left( \frac{I_{2} - \sigma^3}{2}\right)\\
    \end{matrix}\right]
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \xi\\
        \xi
    \end{pmatrix}\nonumber\\
    &= \left(
    \begin{matrix}
        \left[\sqrt{E + p^3} \left( \frac{I_{2} - \sigma^3}{2}\right) + \sqrt{E - p^3}  \left( \frac{I_{2} + \sigma^3}{2}\right)\right]\xi\\
        \\
        \left[\sqrt{E + p^3}  \left( \frac{I_{2} + \sigma^3}{2}\right) + \sqrt{E - p^3}  \left( \frac{I_{2} - \sigma^3}{2}\right)\right]\xi\\
    \end{matrix}\right)
\end{align}

where, we have used the following facts, $\sqrt{m}\, e^{\eta/2} = (m e^\eta)^{1/2} = \sqrt{m \cosh{\eta} + m \sinh{\eta}}$ and, $\sqrt{m}\, e^{-\eta/2} = (m e^{-\eta})^{1/2} = \sqrt{m \cosh{\eta} - m \sinh{\eta}}$.